# How can I make my Sharepoint / Website available online?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2012-r2, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to learn a few things about SharePoint and I would like to figure out what do I have to do to make my content available online so I can access it from my other computer in my work / home so I can add documents to it.

I did some research on how to set up websites on IIS and setting up my DNS host on Windows Server 2012 with some demo html files I've made. I tried to do research online with port forwarding but I can't find info clear enough for me to get the job done.

Could somebody maybe give me some direction on where to look and a checklist on what I need to complete this task? I feel like I'm shooting in the air trying to figure this out. I've never really dabbled in this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some resources you might find useful in getting this setup. It's difficult to say exactly what you need to do without knowing what it is you've already done.

I haven't watched through the channel9 video but according to the description it includes how to setup internet facing sites in an on-premise environment.

Providing SharePoint is up and running, it should just be a case of configuring the Alternate Access Mappings for internet access, DNS and Port Forwarding.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC390

[https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013](https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[The final guide to Alternate Access Mappings](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/The-final-guide-to-551bd75b?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-eMatO__vJxH4S_7QcTFdEA&tduid=(3d2c3ae131d4daa5d86d2ac82b8c13a3)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-eMatO__vJxH4S_7QcTFdEA)()%22)

Comment: Awesome I will look over them soon! Thank you so much! I port forwarded my static up address for the virtual machine server 2012. But I’m not sure how to access the site from another computer, all that comes up is this windows server site. I know the iis and dns host are set up I didn’t not however dabble with the alternate access mapping yet. I wasn’t sure if that was mandatory or not but I have looked into it very little.  I will definitely look into it more.